# Vue2 component not displaying bootstrap dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue child component that displays a bootstrap modal and requires some fields, with one of the fields being a dropdown selection. For whatever reason, the dropdown button doesn't activate, so the dropdown items don't get shown: 'aria-expand' stays false when clicked. My issue is that the code clearly works outside of the component, so I don't really understand what is going wrong. Here's a working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2ro98so/7/) of what I'm going for.

The code I'm using for my Vue component is exactly the same with the exception of

```
`<template>
    <div> 
        // insert jsfiddle code here
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default{}
</script>`
```

The component works fine, with the modal showing when a button is pressed, its only the dropdown that doesnt work. In case its in any way relevant, I'm using [single file vue components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) with laravel.

Comment: Actually i have tried your code and it works great.!!

Comment: You have the code all in a template literal string somewhere?

Comment: @AmrAly in the code in his question its a template literal string.

Comment: @Bert Evans Yes i have just noticed i that.

Comment: check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ky98xbx2/)

Comment: @Saurabh the problem with your fiddle is it isn't a single file vue component which uses a .vue extension, so I don't think we can recreate it that way. It does help to know that its working that way though, so thank you.

Comment: Can you share some kind of small stripped code repo reproducing this.

Comment: @Saurabh First thing tomorrow morning!

Answer (score 9):

After a few hours of tinkering on this, I realized the problem was with my imports. Not only was I importing bootstrap in my app.js file, but I was also importing it in my layout.php which was causing the problem. Make sure you're only importing once!

Comment: I had the same problem and the same solution.

Comment: Same problem, Same solution! Thanks!